# How to change the icons between different versions of visual studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, icons

I installed visual studio 2008 first. Then I installed visual studio 2003. The icons of the solution file(.sln), the object files(.obj) and etc all turn to the icon of vs 2003. How can I change them to vs 2005?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this
http://ycouriel.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-restore-visual-studio-sln-file.html

Or repair the installation of 2008.